# Convert numeric date format (YYYYMMDD; 20150101) into Year-Month

Tags: r, date, zoo

Can anyone of you help in converting the date from `20150101` to abbreviated form `Jan-2015` ?

I tried the below method.

```
x = 20150101
zoo::as.yearmon(x, "%b-%y")
```

But I got the below error

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with the code in the question:

1. the input format is specified as `"%b-%y"` but should be
   `"%y%m"`
2. we wish to use `as.yearmon.character` here rather than
   `as.yearmon.numeric` so the input should be converted to
   `"character"`

Therefore, try this:

```
 library(zoo)
 ym <- as.yearmon(as.character(20150101), "%Y%m")
```

giving:

```
> ym
[1] "Jan 2015"
```

Note that `"yearmon"` objects are internally stored as year + fraction where fraction is 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  Externally they are rendered as an abbreviated month followed by a space and the year as shown.

The above may be sufficient but if not to convert it to a character string with format `"%b-%y"` or `"%b-%Y"` use `format`:

```
format(ym, "%b-%y")
## [1] "Jan-15"

format(ym, "%b-%Y")
## [1] "Jan-2015"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of strptime to convert the string to a date object and format to format to what you want:

```
date = "20150101"
format(strptime(date,format="%Y%m%d"),"%b-%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lubridate` and `zoo` packages:

```
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

x <- "20150101"

as.yearmon(as.Date(ymd(x)))

[1] "jan 2015"
```